# Why doesn't LaTeX vertically center contents of table cells by default?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Or perhaps provides an easier way to do so? Most tables rendered (that I have witnessed) seem to require vertical centering of content in table cells, purely for aesthetics. So what is the reason that LaTeX would make this particular job a 'bit hard' (relatively speaking) than horizontal centering? Is there something under the hood that makes this tricky? What was the design assumption that led to this?

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and this particular question has been itching my mind for a few days now, since every table that I have to include in my published work requires vertical centering of cell contents. I'm guessing this is a common use case that could/should have been factored into TeX by default but isn't. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You start from a wrong point of view, in my opinion: in your model all cells are surrounded by rules, which is not how good looking table should be. Remove all the vertical rules and keep the horizontal ones that separate different blocks of the table: its appearance will improve instantly.

Comment: @egreg - I see your point. But then why is adding 'vertical rules' non-trivial as opposed to horizontal ones? Is this by design/intent? Why so? Hence the question.

Comment: I think we would benefit from an example. What does a typical table that requires this vertical centering look like? Because, at least I, have trouble with coming up with one in my head. Its not so easy to visualize for bear of very little brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my opinion, but to me vertical centering of table cells is a clear lack of taste and typographic sensitivity. Amongst others, vertically centering your table cells will:

- Break the grid / alignment of lines, which is considered a no-go by most typographers for aesthetic reasons, and
- Make reading harder, as one's eyes will need to go up and down to read the information.

Maybe someone with more knowledge about the development of LaTeX can jump in, but my guess is that it wasn't made easy to center cells vertically because it should be avoided in the first place.